# Popover (from ngx-bootstrap) placement isn't working with ngx-datatable + ngx-translate

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, ngx-translate, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to add a popover on a button but the placement isn't good.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

You can expriment it here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-example-ruqwa7

I've been able to find the problem but not the solution.

1. The user clicks on the delete button
2. Html for the popover is appended in the html. But there is nothing in the body because translations aren't calculated yet (I'm trying to understand why)
   [image]
3. a [function](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/e79019652e82dfb4dbf802960a3315d4e45ad699/src/positioning/ng-positioning.ts#L63) calculates the required positioning
4. translations are loaded (too late)

What I noted that was interesting

- In the stackblitz, I made en "emulation" without the datatable (with the red square). In this case it works because the translations are loaded before the position calculation is done
- Without translation, by hardening the content, there is no positioning problem.

Why is the position calculation done after loading the labels? This is obviously due to the ngx-datatable. Because without the datatable, the position is correct.